# Issue with Creating New Container Through Azure DevOps AzurePowershell@5 Task

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have an inline script using Azure Powershell@5 task

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
                  inputs: 
                    azureSubscription: azureServiceConnection
                    scriptType: inlineScript
                    inline: |
                      $storageAccountKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $(resourceGroupName) -Name $(commonStorageName) | Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq "key1"}
                      $sacontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $(commonStorageName) -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey.Value
                      New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $sacontext -Name $(processingDirectory)
```

This is the error that I get:

> Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the
> "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of
> type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to
> type
> "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext".

I know there is another question regarding this same exact error with mismatch Az.Storage versions, but this is an ADO task. I should not need to fiddle around with installing or importing modules. I also tested this on the Azure CLI and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that New-AzureStorageContainer is part of AzureRM PowerShell. To create a container, you must use New-AzStorageContainer from Az Powershell.